# Amperian Loops vs Gaussian Surfaces

Tags: electromagnetism, integration

I am wondering what makes an amperian loops different from a gaussian surface? I know they are used the calculate different things, but when I take the integral how are they different?

This is in the context of freshman physics for engineering .

Comment: It might help if you posted the actual formulas for the integrals you are looking at.  At the freshman physics level, amperian loops usually aren't calculated as true path integrals.  I'd be happy to answer your question, but it's hard for me to resolve confusion without seeing the formulas exactly as they are being presented to you.  If you don't know how to type Tex or MathJax, then a small zoomed-in photo of the formulas might be okay.

Comment: Gaussian surfaces enclose a volume. Amperian loops enclose an area.